# Excluding a set of results based on the result of a TOP 1 query

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a query to retrieve rows when B<>1 for the highest seq_identity for each distinct A.

```
A B seq_identity
----------------
u 0    8

v 1    9

w 0   10
w 1   11

x 1   12
x 0   13
x 1   14

y 0   15
y 1   16
y 0   17

z 1   18
z 0   19
```

In the real table the A values are not ordered; seq_identity is unique.

The query results from the above would be all the 'u', 'y' and 'z' rows:
i.e.

```
u 0 8
y 0 15
y 1 16
y 0 17
z 1 18
z 0 19
```

Comment: Can you clarify the output?  Why no results from the 'y' rows?

Comment: 'y' rows are in the results -
"all the 'u', **'y'** and 'z' rows"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A, MAX(seq_identity)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE B <> 1
    GROUP BY A;
```

Comment: I think my explanation was unclear - I added the exact expected result set.

Comment: @Zaphod I'm confused now. Why wouldn't 'w 0 10' be included?

Comment: Sorry. Having a hard time explaining it. If the highest seq_identity for each set of A has B=1 then exclude the set from the results. The highest seq_identity for the set of 'w' rows is 11 and that row has B=1 so exclude all 'w' rows from the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, MAX(seq_identity)
FROM table_name
WHERE B <> 1
GROUP BY A
```